# Returned vector defined as "std::vector<<error-type>, std::allocator<<error-type>>>

Tags: c++, vector, return

I am trying to return a vector of structs from one object to another. My first idea is to return a reference to the vector. Both object files include the struct in question (the listener struct) and the function doing the returning looks as such:

```
vector<Listener>* Component::GetListeners() {
    vector<Listener> listeners;
    for (int i = 0; i < listenerSize; i++) {
        Listener listener = { id, static_cast<EventType>(Component::listensFor[i]) };
        listeners.push_back(listener);
    }
    return &listeners;
}
```

A vector of listeners is constructed and then the address of the vector is returned

The problem arises when I receive the pointer in my next function:

```
void Entity::AddComponent(Component c) {
    components.push_back(c);
    vector<Listener> *listeners = c.GetListeners();
    for (int i = 0; i < listeners->size; i++) {

    }
}
```

The error occurs at the line:

```
vector<Listener> *listeners = c.GetListeners();
```

The error states that

```
A value of type "std::vector<<error-type>, std::allocator<<error-type>>>*" cannot be used to initialize entity of type "std::vector<<Listener>, std::allocator<<Listener>>>*"
```

I've tried to research this error but have come across nothing to indicate why exactly it assumes the returned vector is defined as error-type. any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I was informed that when I passed the address of listeners, which was a local variable it did not circumvent the destruction of the local variable when the function was finished (actually quite obvious when it was brought to my attention thank you all). Unfortunately even though I have made the adjustments to return the vector by itself rather than its address I am still receiving the exact same error message (minus the pointers of course). My code is now as such:

```
vector<Listener> Component::GetListeners() {
    vector<Listener> listeners;
    for (int i = 0; i < listenerSize; i++) {
        Listener listener = { this, static_cast<EventType>(Component::listensFor[i]) };
        listeners.push_back(listener);
    }
    return listeners;
}

void Entity::AddComponent(Component c) {
    components.push_back(c);
    vector<Listener> listeners = c.GetListeners();
    for (int i = 0; i < listeners.size; i++) {
    }
}
```

**More Code**
Event.h

```
struct Listener {
    Component *component;
    EventType type;
};

enum EventType {
    PhysCol = 0,
    WheelRayCol = 1,
    Accelerate = 2,
    Turn = 3,
    Fire = 4,
    Damage = 5
};

class Event {
public:
    static EventType type;
    Entity *actor;
};
```

Component.h

```
#include "Event.h"
class Component {
private:
    void Invoke(Event *e);
    //int entityID;
    Entity *entity;
    int id;
public:
    static int listensFor[0];
    //static vector<int> listensFor;
    static int listenerSize;
    static ComponentType type;
    bool enabled = true;

    //Component();
    void HandleEvent(Event *event);
    //static Component CreateComponent(ComponentType type);
    vector<Listener> GetListeners();
    int GetID();
    void RegisterEntity(Entity *e);
};

int Component::listenerSize = 0;
```

Component.cpp

```
#include "Component.h"
vector<Listener> Component::GetListeners() {
    vector<Listener> listeners;
    for (int i = 0; i < listenerSize; i++) {
        Listener listener = { this, static_cast<EventType>(Component::listensFor[i]) };
        listeners.push_back(listener);
    }
    return listeners;
}
```

Entity.h

```
#include "Event.h"
class Entity {
public:
    Transform transform;

    Component GetComponent(ComponentType type);
    void HandleEvent(Event *event);
    void AddComponent(Component component);

    int GetId();
    std::string GetTag();
    bool MatchesTag(std::string tag);
private:
    int id;
    std::string tag;
    std::vector<Component> components;
    std::vector<Listener> listeners;
};
```

Entity.cpp

```
#include "Entity.h"
void Entity::AddComponent(Component c) {
    components.push_back(c);
    vector<Listener> l = c.GetListeners();
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size; i++) {
        listeners.push_back(l[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: After your edit, the code you posted looks fine.  Could you post a [mcve] that reproduces the error, or at least the full error text?  Without seeing more my first guess would be a circular include or something similar.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Sure thing, thanks for your interest

Comment: The code you posted is not minimal, complete, or verifiable, but I do see a couple things that are suspect.  You're storing pointers to function parameters in your `Listener` objects, which will become dangling as soon as the function returns, and I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with `static int listensFor[0];`.  I can't paste the code you posted into my editor and compile it though, so I can't actually reproduce the specific error you're seeing.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Sorry it's a big project so getting a minimal is rather tricky. the `static int listensFor[0]` is mostly just a reminder to myself. I am using Component as a base class for a hierarchy and although `static int listensFor[0]` will not be inherited it s a reminder for me to construct a new `listensFor` array for its derived classes. On the other hand, its not a build error I am receiving but an intellisense error before compilation. I just added the Event and EventType Code if that helps, I feel like that's all that should be needed for compilation

Comment: none of these functions are returning references, they are returning pointers. You can and should simply return the vector itself

Answer (score 0):

In Component::GetListeners you are returning the address of a function local variable, one that immediately goes out of scope and is destructed. You would either need to make it not function local or not return the pointer.

If using a modern c++ compiler (either c++11) you could have a return type of "vector" and "return std::move(listeners);" and avoid the copy. My understanding is that even more modern (c++17) compilers will do that automatically.

Comment: You should just return `listeners`.  It will be moved or the copy elided as needed.  You should generally never return `std::move(local_variable)` since it can defeat the compiler's (N)RVO optimizations and isn't needed anyway.

Comment: @Soronel Wow, awesome! a) I can't believe I didn't notice the local destruction. b) What an awesome suggestion. Avoiding the copying is exactly what I am trying to do. Unfortunately though whether I return `std::move(listeners)` or just `listeners` I still get the same error message, is this still because of the local destruction because from my understanding as long as I pass the object it should not be destroyed

Comment: @MilesBudnek Thanks there is so much I don't know but am trying to learn about optimization

Answer (score 0):

`return &listeners;` returns the address of a local variable that is about to be destroyed - that's obviously bad. Just return your vector by value instead. The compiler will most likely elide the copy.

Comment: I am now returning `listeners` by itself (not the address) and for some reason I am still receiving the same error message, which is very strange because what you are saying makes total sense